# Filtration on JPA Encrypted Column in Spring boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, encryption, spring-data-jpa, amazon-kms

I'm currently facing an issue with applying a filter based on an ENUM field at the JPA level. The ENUM field is encrypted in the database and stored as a byte[] datatype. I'm utilizing AWS Key Management Service (KMS) for encryption, and in the domain model, I've implemented an Attribute Converter and used the @Convert annotation for the ENUM field to handle the conversion.

However, I've encountered unexpected behavior when attempting to filter data based on the ENUM field using JPA. I would greatly appreciate any guidance, insights, or suggestions to address this issue. Thank you!

I need to filter data on the basis of encrypted column using JPA Specification.